# What is an equivalent of "except socket.error as (code, msg)" in Python3?

Tags: python, try-except

I have this `try/except` block in Python2 that does not run in Python3 due to the line `except socket.error as (code, msg)`:

```
try:
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept()
except socket.error as (code, msg):
    if code != errno.EINTR:
        raise
    else:
        break
```

What is the equivalent in Python3? Is there a way that works in both Python versions?

Comment: `except socket.error as ex` then you can check `ex.errno` I believe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the PEP that removed the old exceptions, [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#compatibility-strategy), this way should work:

```
try:
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept()
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EINTR:
        raise
    else:
        break
```

Note that in Python > 3.3 `socket.error` is a [*deprecated* alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.error) for `OSError`.